# Mathematical field theory Application in real world and other branches of Mathematics

Tags: field-theory, education, applications, book-recommendation

I need to write work about applications of Mathematical field theory in real world and in other branches of Mathematics. Can someone guide me to an appropriate book, resource?

Thanks,
Denis.

Answer (score 2):

Reed-Solomon Codes and Their Applications

Stephen B. Wicker (Editor), Vijay K. Bhargava (Editor)
ISBN: 978-0-7803-5391-6
336 pages
October 1999, Wiley-IEEE Press

http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0780353919,miniSiteCd-IEEE2.html

Answer (score 1):

Multiantenna modulation uses lattices in number fields (actually division algebras over a number field) as signal constellations. See [here](http://spacetimecodes.blogspot.fi/p/golden-code.html) or [here](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~rekaya/media/Articles_perso/Golden_Code.pdf).

Comment: Assuming that *field* to you is a structure of abstract algebra with two operations (instead of a vector field or some such).